# Magento 1.8 blocks creating troubles

Tags: magento

I am a new guy in Magento.
I try to add text on checkout page after available shipping methods.
I cant understand how blocks, temlates work.

So I have created new module.

[image]

I have read all manuals but did not get result needed. 
How can I configure xml file for displaying simple text after available shipping methods?

[image]

Comment: In app\design\frontend\your_package\your_themet\template\checkout\onepage\shipping_method\available.phtml, add your text after the closing </dl> tag.

Comment: @DalbinShimy thx, but I try all the ways but nothing happens, default template loading

Comment: First clear cache from admin and then changes reflect in front end.

Comment: @JitendraPatel cache disabled

Comment: Copy default theme file to your theme file and add dummy text for testing. For example : app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checko‌​ut\onepage\shipping_‌​method\available.pht‌​ml  Copy to app\design\frontend\your_package\your_theme\template\checko‌​ut\onepage\shipping_‌​method\available.pht‌​ml

Comment: @JitendraPatel see http://shot.qip.ru/00U9NE-2xvshx9cM/ Is anything wrong in a path? Nothing happens in this case. I dont know why

Comment: Do one thing enable template path on in front end and check exact file path. use this link for enable template hint : http://insync.co.in/how-to-enable-template-path-and-block-name-hints-in-magento-commerce/

Comment: @JitendraPatel thanks, good tool. But loaded default templates. http://shot.qip.ru/00U9NE-6xvshx9cN/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149213/discussion-between-jitendra-patel-and-spy-enot).

Comment: Confirm you have selected insurance theme in admin like below.
Go to admin >> system >> design >> your theme ( Insurance )

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps see below:

**Step 1-** First Enable Template Path Hints: There are two ways

**a)** Read this tutorial:http://support.magerewards.com/article/1534-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints

**b)** Or Install Template path hints extension. Goto the url https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html

And in this url page you find how to install and configure templates path hints extension.

**Step 2-** Goto checkout page.

Now you can see red color strips in which all file url are coming. for using this you can easily identify file location.